# Why have I just got a terminal on restarting my Ubuntu VM?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, apt, upgrade

I think I managed to upgrade from 14.04.1 to 16.04.1, but after I restarted it, it had a black screen. I shut it down and restarted it, then I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> for advanced settings secure boot, and now I only have a terminal, and I'm not sure why. How do I get Ubuntu to operate normally?

[image: Screen shot]

Text in screenshot:

```
The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

E: Error: BrokenCount > 0run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 255

$ sudo boot
[sudo] password for laptoppwthentwoexclamationmarks:
sudo: boot: command not found

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
laptoppwthentwoexclamationmarks@laptopPW-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`? Could you please post program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry for so slow geting back to you. E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: Entering "sudo dpkg --configure -a " I got a new screen purple with a box with a heading "Configuring libssl1.0.0:amd64"   there are services installed on your system that need to be restarted when certain libraries, such as libpam, libc, and libssl, are upgraded. Since these restarts may cause interruptions of service for the system,

Comment: you will normally be prompted on each restart. You can choose this option to avoid being prompted; instead, all necessary restarts will be done for you automatically so you can avoid being asked questions on each library upgrade.
Restart services during package upgrads without asking?
<Yes> <No>

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message describes that you have packages that are broken, for whatever reason. This could have been caused by a bad `dpkg` command being ran in the past or power was lost during an update, etc.

As the error describes you need to run:

```
sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a
```

which means "reconfigure all my packages" which will validate the integrity of files on disk and ensure configurations etc. are not corrupted.

Comment: Is that just for the 14.04 vertion as I get dpkg: error: unknown option --reconfigure